# When using tf.get_variable instead of tf.Variable(), it seems that the parameters initialized in every epoch

Tags: tensorflow

This is just a simple conv-net. I just used `tf.Variable()` before, then I found I need a shared variable to see the test result. So I use `tf.get_variable()` instead of `tf.Variable()`, but I found the loss could not be decreased in the training process. I think maybe there is something wrong in my code, but I could not fix it. It seems like the parameters are initialized in every epoch, how to fix it in every epoch?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import math

import tensorflow.python.platform
import tensorflow as tf

import global_define as gd

# The MNIST dataset has 10 classes, representing the digits 0 through 9.
# NUM_CLASSES = 16

# # The MNIST images are always 28x28 pixels.
# IMAGE_SIZE = 28
# IMAGE_PIXELS = 784

def weight_variable(name,shape):
    return tf.get_variable(name=name,shape=shape,initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

def bias_variable(name,shape):
    return tf.get_variable(name=name,shape=shape,initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))


def conv2d_same(x,W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')

def conv2d_valid(x,W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='VALID')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x,ksize=[1,2,2,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')

def max_pool_3x3(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x,ksize=[1,3,3,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')

def inference(image_input,images_input_test):
    with tf.variable_scope("what_the_fuck") as scope:

        images=tf.reshape(image_input,[-1,32,32,1])
        W_conv1=weight_variable("weight1",[5,5,1,9])
        b_conv1=bias_variable("bias1",[9])
        h_conv1=tf.nn.relu(conv2d_valid(images,W_conv1)+b_conv1)
        h_pool1=max_pool_3x3(h_conv1)
        norm1=tf.nn.lrn(h_pool1,4,bias=1.0,alpha=0.001/9.0,beta=0.75,name='norm1')



        W_conv2=weight_variable("weight2",[5,5,9,16])
        b_conv2=bias_variable("bias2",[16])
        h_conv2=tf.nn.relu(conv2d_same(norm1,W_conv2)+b_conv2)
        h_pool2=max_pool_3x3(h_conv2)

        norm2=tf.nn.lrn(h_pool2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                        name='norm2')

        W_fc1=weight_variable("weight3",[7*7*16,1024])
        b_fc1=bias_variable("bias3",[1024])
        h_pool2_flat=tf.reshape(norm2,[-1,7*7*16])
        h_fc1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat,W_fc1)+b_fc1)

        #keep_prob=tf.placeholder("float")
        h_fc1_drop=tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1,0.8)

        W_fc2=weight_variable("weight4",[1024,384])
        b_fc2=bias_variable("bias4",[384])
        h_fc2=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop,W_fc2)+b_fc2)

        h_fc2_drop=tf.nn.dropout(h_fc2,0.8)

        W_fc3=weight_variable("weight5",[384,gd.NUM_CLASSES])
        b_fc3=bias_variable("bias5",[gd.NUM_CLASSES])
        h_fc3=tf.maximum(tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc2_drop,W_fc3)+b_fc3),1e-30)

    return h_fc3


def loss(y_conv,labels):
    batch_size=tf.size(labels)
    labels=tf.expand_dims(labels,1)
    indices=tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0,batch_size),1)
    concated=tf.concat(1,[indices,labels])
    onehot_labels=tf.sparse_to_dense(concated,tf.pack([batch_size,10]),1.0,0.0)
    cross_entropy=tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv,onehot_labels,name='xentropy')
    loss=tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy,name='xentropy_mean')
    #tf.summary.scalar('xentropy_mean',loss)
    return loss

def training(loss,learning_rate):
    tf.scalar_summary(loss.op.name,loss)
    optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    global_step=tf.Variable(0,name='global_step',trainable=False)
    train_op=optimizer.minimize(loss,global_step=global_step)
    return train_op

def evaluation(y_conv,labels):
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(y_conv, labels, 1)
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct, tf.int32))
```

and this is another part of the code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import os.path
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import  re
import datetime
import utils
import tensorflow as tf
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import global_define as gd
import lenet5
from utils import tile_raster_images

TRAIN_FILE = 'train.tfrecords'
VALIDATION_FILE = 'validation.tfrecords'
TEST_FILE='test.tfrecords'

flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
#FLAGS = None
flags.DEFINE_string('tfrecord_dir', 
    '/home/scw4750/Liuhongkun/tfrecord/kaggle_zooplankton/image2tfrecord/zooplankton_rotate_dataset_10_classes/shuffled_32_32/tfrecord_32_32/', 'Directory to put the training data.')
flags.DEFINE_string('filename', 'train.tfrecords', 'Directory to put the training data.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 100, 'Batch size.  '
                     'Must divide evenly into the dataset sizes.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_epochs', None, 'Batch size.  '
                     'Must divide evenly into the dataset sizes.')

flags.DEFINE_integer('learning_rate', 0.01,'balabala')
flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 50000,'balabala')
flags.DEFINE_string('model_dir','Modal/model'+re.sub(r'[^0-7]','',str(datetime.datetime.now()))+'/','balabala')
flags.DEFINE_string('tensorevents_dir','tensorboard_event/event_wth'+re.sub(r'[^0-7]','',str(datetime.datetime.now()))+'/','balabala')
flags.DEFINE_string('log_dir','Log_data/log'+re.sub(r'[^0-7]','',str(datetime.datetime.now()))+'/','balabala')
flags.DEFINE_string('pic_dir','Pic/Pictures_input'+re.sub(r'[^0-7]','',str(datetime.datetime.now()))+'/','balabala')

if not os.path.exists(FLAGS.log_dir):
  os.makedirs(FLAGS.log_dir)

if not os.path.exists(FLAGS.tensorevents_dir):
  os.makedirs(FLAGS.tensorevents_dir)

if not os.path.exists(FLAGS.model_dir):
    os.makedirs(FLAGS.model_dir)

if not os.path.exists(FLAGS.pic_dir):
    os.makedirs(FLAGS.pic_dir)



def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader=tf.TFRecordReader()
    _,serialized_exampe=reader.read(filename_queue)
    features=tf.parse_single_example(serialized_exampe,
        features={
        'image_raw':tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
        'label':tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64)
        })
    image=tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'],tf.uint8)
    image.set_shape([gd.IMAGE_PIXELS])
    image=tf.cast(image,tf.float32)*(1./255)-0.5
    label=tf.cast(features['label'],tf.int32)
    return image,label

def do_eval(sess,eval_correct,log_name):
    true_count=0
    for step in xrange(FLAGS.batch_size):
        #print(sess.run(eval_correct))
        true_count+=sess.run(eval_correct)

    precision=float(true_count)/(FLAGS.batch_size*FLAGS.batch_size)
    # true_count=sess.run(eval_correct)
    # precision=float(true_count)/FLAGS.batch_size
    print('  Num examples: %d  Num correct: %d  Precision @ 1: %0.04f' %
            (FLAGS.batch_size*FLAGS.batch_size, true_count, precision))
    logfile=open(log_name,'a')
    logfile.write('  Num examples: %d  Num correct: %d  Precision : %0.04f' %
            (FLAGS.batch_size, true_count, precision))
    logfile.close()
    return precision


def inputs(train,batch_size,num_epochs):
    if not num_epochs:num_epochs=None
    if train=='train':
        filename=os.path.join(FLAGS.tfrecord_dir,TRAIN_FILE)
    elif train=='validation':
        filename=os.path.join(FLAGS.tfrecord_dir,VALIDATION_FILE)
    else:
        filename=os.path.join(FLAGS.tfrecord_dir,TEST_FILE)

    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        filename_queue=tf.train.string_input_producer([filename],num_epochs=None)

        image,label=read_and_decode(filename_queue)
        images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [image, label], batch_size=batch_size,
        capacity=1000 + 3 * batch_size,num_threads=1,
        min_after_dequeue=1000)

        return images, sparse_labels

def run_training(log_name):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():

        images,labels=inputs(train='train',batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
            num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)

        images_test,labels_test =inputs(train='test', batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
                              num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)

        logits=lenet5.inference(images)

        scope.reuse_variables()
        logits_test=lenet5.inference(images_test)
        loss=lenet5.loss(logits,labels)

        train_op=lenet5.training(loss,FLAGS.learning_rate)

        eval_correct=lenet5.evaluation(logits,labels)


        eval_correct_test=lenet5.evaluation(logits_test,labels_test)

        init_op=tf.initialize_all_variables()

        #tf.scalar_summary('Train_loss',loss)

        summary_op=tf.merge_all_summaries()


        saver=tf.train.Saver()

        config = tf.ConfigProto()
        config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
        #config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)


        with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:

            sess.run(init_op)


            summary_writer=tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.tensorevents_dir,sess.graph)
            coord=tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads=tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)

            try:
                step=0

                while not coord.should_stop():
                    start_time=time.time()
                    _,loss_value,images_out=sess.run([train_op,loss,images])


                    duration=time.time()-start_time
                    if step % 100 == 0:
                        print('Step %d: loss = %.2f (%.3f sec)' % (step, loss_value,
                                                         duration))
                        logfile=open(log_name,'a')
                        logfile.write('Step %d: loss = %.2f (%.3f sec)\n' % (step, loss_value, duration))
                        logfile.close()


                        summary_str=sess.run(summary_op)
                        summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str,step)


                    if (step + 1) % 1000 == 0 or (step + 1) == FLAGS.max_steps:
                        checkpoint_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir, 'model.ckpt')
                        saver.save(sess, checkpoint_file, global_step=step)
                        concat_img=Image.fromarray(
            tile_raster_images(
                X=images_out,
                img_shape=(32, 32),
                tile_shape=(10, 10)
            ))
                        concat_img.save(FLAGS.pic_dir+str(step)+'_train'+'.jpg')

                        print('Train:')
                        do_eval(sess,eval_correct,log_name)
                        print('Test:')
                        do_eval(sess,eval_correct_test,log_name)

                    step+=1
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print('Done training for %d epochs, %d steps.' % (1001, step))
            finally:
                coord.request_stop()

            coord.join(threads)
            #sess.close()
if __name__=="__main__":
    log_name=str(FLAGS.log_dir)+'lenet_zooplankton_'+'learningrate_'+str(FLAGS.learning_rate)+'_'+re.sub(r'[^0-7]','',str(datetime.datetime.now()))+'.txt'
    f=open(log_name,'w')
    f.close()
    run_training(log_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
logits=lenet5.inference(images)
tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
logits_test=lenet5.inference(images_test)
```

and then remove everything below scope.reuse_variables in your inference function.